# Path parameters ignored by AWS API Gateway using proxy+

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a REST API on the AWS API Gateway.  It has one resource, `/{proxy+}`, that is configured with the `ANY` method.  The integration request is setup to be a `VPC_PROXY`, meaning its using a `VPC Link`.  The VPC link is to a network load balancer that is fronting an app I have running on an ECS cluster using Fargate.

When using the console's option to test the API, I can confirm that requests are reaching my app but the resource being requested is always `/` according to my logging.  If I attempt to set the `{proxy}` value in the method test screen on the console, it seems like my app only ever gets requests for `/`.  If I set `{proxy}` to something like `widget/5`, the response I receive is as if I was request `/`.

I'm wondering if there is some way to troubleshoot this, scouring the AWS documentation I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your integration, the endpoint URL should be `http://loadbalancerurl/{proxy}`. I couldn't find any documentation specifically for VPC Link integration, but there is a tutorial for [HTTP proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) which has similar steps.

If you are using openapi spec, the integration section would look something like this:

```yaml
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  uri: "http://loadbalancerurl/{proxy}"
  responses:
    default:
      statusCode: "200"
  requestParameters:
    integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"
  passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
  connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
  connectionId: "your-vpclink-id"
  httpMethod: "ANY"
  type: "http_proxy"
```

When using the console, `integration.request.path.proxy: "method.request.path.proxy"` mapping was added automatically when I added {proxy} to my endpoint URL.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is by adding the following properties:

```
Resources:
  APIGWProxyMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RequestParameters: 
        method.request.path.proxy: true # enable proxy
      Integration:
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.path.proxy: method.request.path.proxy # map method proxy param to integration proxy param
      ... # the rest of integration property
    ... # other properties
```

Articles that helped:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-parameter-error/